# How do I implement Enumerations in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails version: 4.2.0
OS:            Windows 7 (64-bit)

Hello, For example lets say I have a rails app with a **posts** model.

If I wanted the post model to have a permissions column, which could take on one of several values **[public, private, unlisted]**

The way I would implement this would be to add a integer column to the **posts** model, but checking this value would quickly become confusing because I would have to memorize which value corresponds to which permission.

how could I implement an enumeration into this so I could do checks like

```
if post.visibility == POST_PUBLIC or post.visibility == POST_PRIVATE
```

Comment: There's a feature in Rails designed exactly for this purpose: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Rails 4.1 you can have `enum` attributes in ActiveRecord models. For example:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum visibility: [:public, :private, :unlisted]
  ..
end
```

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html